# Understanding a SQL Server error message - what's meant by "identity column in table 'sessions' "?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm curious about the error I just got after inserting this data, like so:

```
insert into bi_sessions 
values (295377778,  '04dzzzf7-e66c-4e6d-9c42-465a16546e34', 1,  43223810,   48, 1043,   'BELGIUM BEER Survey (QA)', 54, 'Synovate Panel',   -1  , 2.5,  6,  3,  2.5 , 2.5,  '2010-04-01 00:00:00.000',  '2010-04-01 00:00:30.000',  -1  ,3, 1,  '000708c8507696c06f777',    '68.200.93.212',    20, '04dea8f7-e66c-4e6d-9c42-465a16546777'  , -1,   NULL,   55743   ,9  , 'Untargeted', 3,  2,  2016,   'General',  1966,   '2010-04-01 00:00:22.000',  1966,   '2010-04-01 00:00:32.000',  1,  9,  'English - United States',  'Federated Sample', 1)
```

The error message reads:

> *An explicit value for the identity column in table 'sessions' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.*

It's confusing - what is an *identity column* ?

Comment: It means one of your fields is an IDENTITY in the table 'sessions' and you can't write to that field.

Comment: It is a column that can't be repeated, and in this case, it might be an auto incrementing field, thus not allowing you to ecplicitly insert a value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table has an [identity column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), meaning that you have a column that automatically increment its value when a row is inserted. Since this is, well, automatic, you can't explicitely insert a value into that column unless you use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`. So, in your case, you shoul do:

```
INSERT INTO bi_sessions(<list of all non-identity column>)
VALUES (<your values>)
```

Answer (score 1):

An `IDENTITY` column is a column where SQL Server itself determines the value. It's typically used to generate unique identity values as primary keys for a table (like your `sessions` table) - other RDBMS call this an **auto-increment** or **auto-numbering** column.

Since SQL Server determines those values itself, you're not allowed to **insert** your own values into that column.

In order to do that, you need to **explicitly** specify the list of columns in your `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.bi_sessions(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
VALUES (...., ..., .......)
```

Comment: Of course, you should  explicitly list all columns in an insert anyway even without an identity! Failing to list columns is a SQL antipattern.